# How to map dynamic columns of database in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ado.net

How to map dynamic columns of database in web application
[Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9vLJ.png)

image is data set i am getting from data base and highlighted columns are dynamic generated by pivot, Now problem that I dont know what would be the names of columns as they are dynamic and i have to map the in my application. 
Here is the code my application where I have to map them

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[1].Rows)
{
    var result = new
    {
        EmployeeName = Convert.ToString(row["EmployeeName"]),
        UserName = Convert.ToString(row["UserName"]),
        fkPayrollSetupId = Convert.ToInt32(row["fkPayrollSetupId"]),
        fkEmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(row["fkEmployeeId"]),
        Tax = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Tax"]),
        AnnualSalary = Convert.ToDecimal(row["AnnualSalary"]),
        TotalMonthlySalary = Convert.ToDecimal(row["TotalMonthlySalary"]),

    };

    lstSalaryReportModel.Add(result);
}

dicModel.Add("SalaryReport", lstSalaryReportModel);
```

I am using ado.net.

Comment: you are asking about ADO.NET but you are tagging it in ASP.NET.WEB.API.

Comment: I am using asp.net web api i have to map them in api

Comment: well you can transform datatable to dictonary

Comment: Do you know the order of the columns in the returned DataRow? If you do it should be easy to just get them with the index. Another alternative is to go through the associated DataTable and to the DataColumnCollection and iterate through it. If you don't know the order nor the names then I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: I also dont know the index its depending on the value in table